# Creating a dynamic html form

Tags: html, forms, dynamic

I would like to create a form that changes dynamically.

I have a form for creating a project (with fields such as: project_name, project_description...) and the project can have any amount (bigger or equal to 0) of categories.

What i want is to display a button which would give the user the option to add another category field. In addition I would also like the option for category fields to be "deleteable" by the user (if he changes his mind or made a mistake). What would be the best way to do so. I would like an Ajax type solution.

My solution so far is to leave an empty div beneath the last category and onclick of the button to load another field into that div with yet another div which will be used for the next div. Not to happy with this solution since i now have to count how many fields I have and give each div it's own id which complicates the matter even more.

Is there a more simple solution to this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are trying to add fields dynamically with a button, you can easily do so by doing something like the following:

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <p>
        <label>Name:</label> <input type="text">
        <label>Age:</label> <input type="text">
        <span class="remove">Remove</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="add">Add fields</span>
    </p>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".add").click(function() {
    $("form > p:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("form > p:last-child");
    return false;
});

$(".remove").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UeSsu/1/

Comment: Amazing! so simple... but how would i handle this if for example i wanted to send the edited result out how would I number each of the separate fields so that it can be then read easily by an outside function (entering the information into a database for example)

Comment: Not really what i wanted since to remove a category all categories added after it must be deleted.

Comment: @nayish I would give them all identical names, but I'd give them a name that references an array 0 for instance, instead of category1, category2, etc, I'd name each HTML element "category[]". (This works in PHP.) This way, everything gets written to an array, and you can simply iterate through it. This should work well with the initial solution.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution, however i get a strange result when i implement it on my site. In stead of one additional p tag (with the fields) i get two added at the time. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: this is awesome

Comment: This solution only works if the user doesn't delete all elements, it copies the add button if they do.

Comment: This is really cool, but if I delete all elements, and try to re-add it just duplicates the Add fields since nothing else exists. May be a check for if elements > 1 in the remove portion can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I started to write a form generator is based on a definition in JSON a while back. It works but could use some enhancements. It's written using Prototype.js but it wouldn't be a huge effort to port it over to jQuery.

You're welcome to steal [the code](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/jameslab/jsonform/). (just view source)

Comment: The JSON block holds the definition of the form. So essentially by using JS to manipulate the form defintion you control a what's in the form dynamically.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but I'd just thought I'd point out this breaks if you remove all the blocks

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar. To delete fields I didn't really removed fields. I just hidden them with a `display:none` and had a hidden `input` "delete" that I trigger to true. Then, the page receiving the result knows which field is to be deleted in the database.

They are not deleted before the form is submitted. It's like a "two pass" conception. But if you don't really need a true ajax, it works fine. Otherwise you need your JS remove function to call the server and tell to delete the field with its id. A little bit more complex to code.

Comment: Hiding things with CSS has serious potential consequences.  Adding them dynamically with js is a better way to go.

Comment: One word: *CSRF*

Comment: @TheRealChx101 can you elaborate? Just curious. Can't find why this would be a CSRF vulnerabilty.