# Creating a dynamic add users form in devise

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I'm using devise in my rails 3.2 application.

I have a users/new page where an admin user fills in an email address and then a user is created with a random password.

All of this works fine.

What I want to do is to create a dynamic form so that the admin can create as many users as they want. There should be an 'add user field' button and a 'delete user field' button that allows generation of new fields for users.

I can't seem to get the jquery to work with the form.

I tried using what was described in this stackoverflow question:

[Creating a dynamic html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156790/creating-a-dynamic-html-form)

My code is like this (Note I'm using @manager instead of @user in the form so as not to confuse rails with the current_user. Still @manager creates a devise user.

users/new

```
<%= form_for(@manager) do |f| %>
<% if @manager.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@manager.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this manager from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @manager.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<span class="add">Add fields</span>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add").click(function() {
    $(".field:first").clone(true).insertBefore(this);
  return false;
  });
});
```

Still, when I click on Add fields, nothing happens. I'm pretty sure if I can get the form to submit the right parameters, then I can work the controller to do what I want it to do.

Basically, why isn't the clone function working in the above example and how can I get a dynamic form to create multiple devise users at once.

Also, I left out the delete fields method since it obviously isn't working either.

EDIT: I changed the selector to ".add" and I changed ".field" to ".field:first", but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"add" is not a valid selector.... you need a "." prefix to represent that it is for a class. Without prefix you are looking for a tagName of "add"

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
 $(".add").click(function() {....
```

If you click more than once you will then be adding as many elements with class="field" as exist in form due to your ".field" selector.

You should probably use something like:

```
   $(".field:first").clone(true).....
```

Comment: So for some reason, after I switched away from what you recommended and then changed back it started working. I guess I had a typo or something. Still, I'm pretty sure you answered my question