# Dynamic HTML form issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dynamic

I'm trying to create a dynamic HTML form in order to create some guests user and populate this in a DB.

I tried to follow the instruction in the thread below :
[Creating a dynamic html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156790/creating-a-dynamic-html-form/39307843#39307843)

But I can't make it work on my server.
I'm really not familiar with JavaScript in HTML (Usually I prefer to use Python), so please excuse me for this dummy question.

Below is (one of) the HTML code I tried :

```js
$('#btnAdd').click(function() {
  var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
  var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

  // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
  var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

  // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
  newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);
  newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'email' + newNum).attr('name', 'email' + newNum);

  // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
  $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

  // enable the "remove" button
  $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');

  // business rule: you can only add 5 names
  if (newNum == 5) {
    $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});

$('#btnDel').click(function() {
  var num = $('.clonedInput').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
  $('#input' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

  // enable the "add" button
  $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', '');

  // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
  if (num - 1 == 1) {
    $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});


$('#btnDel').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <Title>My First dynamic form test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
        Email: <input type="text" name="email1" id="email1" />
      </div>

      <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another entry" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove last entry" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

PS : by the way, if somebody has any idea to do the same (as simple) in Python please feel free to share :)

Comment: Your code is executing before the page has finished loading. You might want to move the 2nd script element after the </form> tag.

Comment: remove the disabled attr from the delete button like so: `$('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);` or use `$('#btnDel').removeAttr('disabled')` ... do the same for the add button

Answer (score 0):

You have the following points:

- execute your js only when the document is ready
- to disable/enble instead of attr you need to use prop
- the length property is always a number, so you do not need Number constructor

```js
//
// wrap your code in document ready:
// running rour code before the elements are not yet loaded is an error
//
$(function () {
  $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length;    // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    var newNum = num + 1;                   // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

    // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
    var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().find('[id]').andSelf().attr('id', function(index, attr) {
      return attr.replace(/[0-9]*$/, '') + newNum;
    }).attr('name', function(index, attr) {
      return (attr === undefined) ? undefined : attr.replace(/[0-9]*$/, '') + newNum;
    }).eq(0);

    // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
    $('#input' + num).after(newElem);

    // enable the "remove" button
    $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', false);

    // business rule: you can only add 5 names
    if (newNum == 5)
      $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  $('#btnDel').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedInput').length;    // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    $('#input' + num).remove();        // remove the last element

    // enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', false);

    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if (num - 1 == 1)
      $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', true);
  });


  $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>



<form id="myForm">
    <div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1"/>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email1" id="email1"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another entry"/>
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove last entry"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding to use prop() ... Also note the second `newElem.children` line targets the wrong element. Use `:last` or `:eq(1)` or `:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: well there's another way to do it... but it may have been better to keep it similar to the OP's code

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I think there is something wrong with my server, because even if I add the script after the </form> nothing happens when I click on the buttons ...

Comment: Yes, I put this before my script: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

Comment: You forgot the starting https. Try with: [this link](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js) and let me know. Did you wrapped your code inside document ready? ($(function () {)

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It works with this new link :) Apparently I tried also with http, but it needed https in the link

Comment: Just one last question : how can I reuse the script for multiple form in the same page ? Thanks

Comment: Copy the script in a file and include it with the same syntax but different name you already do for jQuery. Add this other line after including jQuery. The URL instead must be different from jQuery.